# While Dragging, created marker with connected polyline from toolbar,previous polyline between two marker deleted using leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, leaflet-draw

When dragging created marker with connected polyline from toolbar,previous polyline between two marker automatically deleted  or auto connect from with new draggable marker?

I'm try to dragging marker with polyline,so when i dropping two marker from toolbar and creating polyline between them and then after dragging it is working fine.but while creating another two more marker with polyline and dragging, previous connect marker with polyline,from marker between polyline deleted automatically,and display like that line going to connect/replace with current draggable marker.

so how to solve issue polyline disappear or deleted automatically.

here is code which with i'm trying dragging functionality for marker and polyline after drawing on map from custom toolbar:

```
var zoomValue = 2;   
// center of the map                   
var center = [42.94033923363183, -108.63281250000001];  
// Create the map
var map = L.map('map',{drawControl: false,center,minZoom:1,zoom:zoomValue});

// Set up the OSM layer
L.tileLayer(
'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Data © <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
    maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);

var myFeatureGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(map).on("click", markerOnClick);  

var markers;
var latlngs = Array();
var polyline;         

map.on('click', function(e) {         
    if(self.isclickedEvent == true){            
        var firefoxIcon1 = L.icon({
            iconUrl: self.sourceImage,
            iconSize: [25,41]                 
           });
        markers = L.marker([e.latlng.lat,e.latlng.lng], {icon: firefoxIcon1,draggable: true}).addTo(myFeatureGroup)
            .bindPopup(customPopup,iDiv)                
            .on('dragstart', dragStartHandler)
            .on('drag', dragHandler)
            .on('dragend', dragEndHandler);

        map.fitBounds(myFeatureGroup.getBounds());
        myFeatureGroup.addLayer(markers);               
});

function markerOnClick(event){
        if(self.drawPolyline == true){
            latlngs.push(event.latlng);                
            if(latlngs.length == 2){
              drawPolyline();
            }
        }            
}

//To draw polyline
function drawPolyline(){        
    polyline = L.polyline(latlngs, {color: 'blue',weight:6}).bindPopup("PolyLine").addTo(myFeatureGroup);        

    // zoom the map to the polyline
    map.fitBounds(polyline.getBounds());
    myFeatureGroup.addLayer(polyline);      
    latlngs =Array();
    self.drawPolyline=false;      
}

// starting of drag events
var p;
var p2;
var polylineLatlng;            
function dragStartHandler (e){
    var latlng = this.getLatLng();
    myFeatureGroup.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    if (layer instanceof L.Polyline)
    {
        p2= layer._latlngs;
        for (var i = 0; i < p2.length; i++) {
            if(latlng.equals(p2[i])){
            p = layer._latlngs;
            polylineLatlng = i;
        }
       }
    }
  });              
}
function dragHandler (e){
    var latlng = this.getLatLng();            
    myFeatureGroup.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        if (layer instanceof L.Polyline)
        {
            var pipelineLayer = layer;
            p.splice(polylineLatlng,1,latlng);
            pipelineLayer.setLatLngs(p);
            myFeatureGroup.addLayer(pipelineLayer);             
        }
    });
}
function dragEndHandler (e) {
    //console.log(e);
    delete this.polylineLatlng;
}
```